# UITextField in UITableViewCell

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5, uitableview, ios4

I want to place UItextField in UITableViewCell but I have problem. Text field don't appear. This is my code:

```
-(id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString         *)reuseIdentifier {
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self) {
        self.textField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 120.0f, 45.0f)];
        self.textField.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];

        [self.contentView addSubview:self.textField];
    }

    return self;
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    TextFieldCell *cell = (TextFieldCell*)[tableView  dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[TextFieldCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }
    switch (indexPath.row) {
        case 1:
            cell.textField.placeholder = @"Username";
            break;
        case 2:
            cell.textField.placeholder = @"Password";
            break;
        case 3:
            cell.textField.placeholder = @"Server Address";
            break;
        case 4:
            cell.textField.placeholder = @"Description";
            break;            
        default:
            break;
    }

    return cell;
}
```

I test and initWithStyle method is called.Can someone help me?

Comment: Hav you tried inserting an NSLog statement in your initWithStyle method to make sure it is getting called?  Are you setting the value of your textField's text property in cellForRowAtIndexPath?

Comment: Yes I tried with NSLog. See my edtited post.

Comment: Could you show the property declaration for `self.textField`?

Comment: Thanks man. I have set my property to weak. This was the mistake. Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IF you have **.xib** file for **TextFieldCell** then drag and drop textview and set all properties form Interface builder else
**you can create only **.XIB*** to use as TableViewCell by*

**In .h file**

IBOutlet UITableViewCell* CUSTOM_CELL_XIB;

**In .m file in cellForRowAtIndexPath method**

```
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";


UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

if (cell == nil) 
{
    [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CUSTOM_CELL_XIB" owner:self options:nil]; 
    cell = CUSTOM_CELL_XIB;
}
```

and directly drag and drop textField or whatever UI you want, I think it is efficient way for custom cell creation.

This will perfectly work